# Discord bot doesn't read user activity and is only online

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to python but I always wanted to make discord bot and now I'm trying to make one but it simply isin't working how it should, what I did wrong, can someone help?

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Czas na pogrom!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == ".":
        await message.channel.send("sznio")

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if after.activity is not None:
        if str(after.activity) == 'League of Legends':
            user = after
            await user.send("Chuj ci w dupe, wylacz ligusie, ten no")
        elif isinstance(after.activity, discord.Spotify):
            user = after
            await user.send("Ale muzyczka gra ni")
            with open('funk.gif', 'rb') as file:
                await user.send(file=discord.File(file, 'funk.gif'))

client.run('token')
```

Comment: You need to import and enable the members Intent in your Developer Portal and code.

Comment: This is pretty advanced for someone new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new and just learning, but I see problems in the code.
I don't see the token being downloaded anywhere.
You can provide it in the `config.json` file along with the prefix.

```json
{
   "prefix": ".",
   "token": "your_token"
}
```

Intents are missing, and this is more or less what the program that will definitely run the bot should look like.
Make sure you have installed discord.py:

```
pip install discord.py[VOICE]
```

```py
# main.py
import discord
import json

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.presences = True
intents.typing = True
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Function to read configuration data from a JSON file
def get_config():
     with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
         data = json.load(f)
         return data

config = get_config()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
     print("Czas na pogrom!")

# the rest of the code

# Setting the token based on data from the JSON file
token = config["token"]

client.run(token)
```

Remember to adjust the code and JSON file with your actual token and configuration as needed.